# How to call a function after displayed frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to do speech recognition in my code. There is multiple frame i used in this code. The start page actually only the menu for start the application. There is a button to start the app in the startPage. After that the PageOne will appear. But i want to do speech recognition in the page one. If i call the speechh function, the speech recognition will start right after i run the code. I want to ask what should i do to make the speech recognition will start in the page One after i clicked the button in the startPage?

```
import tkinter as tk   # python3
#import Tkinter as tk   # python
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import speech_recognition as sr
import threading, time
import sys


TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")
str=""
arr=["E", "F P", "T O Z", "L P E D", "P E C F D", "E D F C Z P", "F E L O P Z D", "D E F P O T E C", "L E F O D P C T", "F D P L T C E O", "P E Z O L C F T D"]
page=["PageOne", "PageTwo"]

def speechh():
    # while True:
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Say something!")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    # Speech recognition using Google Speech Recognition
    try:
        # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
        # to use another API key, use r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")
        # instead of r.recognize_google(audio)
        str = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(str)
        print("You said: " + str)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

    asd = ""

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        # sys.stdin.read(1)
        for F,geometry in zip((StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo), ('1940x800', '1940x800', '1940x800')):
            # sys.stdin.read(1)
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            # store the frame and the geometry for this frame
            self.frames[page_name] = (frame, geometry)

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame("StartPage")
    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame, geometry = self.frames[page_name]
        # change geometry of the window
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.geometry(geometry)
        frame.tkraise()
    def on_start(self):
        # for x in page:
        # self.show_frame("PageOne")
        # self.after_idle(speechh)
        for x in page:
            self.show_frame(x)
            speechh()
        # time.sleep(10)
        # speechh()
        # sys.stdin.read(1)
        # self.show_frame("PageTwo")
        # self.after_idle(speechh)


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        fname = "coba2.gif"
        cv = tk.Canvas(self, bg="pink")
        cv.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\Shintia Tamara\\PycharmProjects\\ProjectAI\\coba2.gif")
        cv.create_image(10, 10, image = img, anchor = "nw")
        btn1 = tk.Button(cv, text="QUIT", height=2, width=20, bg="#686DCE", borderwidth=0,
                      fg="white", font=('Sans', '10', 'bold'))
        btn1.pack(side='right', padx=50, pady=50, anchor='se')
        btn2 = tk.Button(cv, text="START", height=2,command=controller.on_start, width=20, bg="#686DCE", borderwidth=0, fg="white",
                      font=('Sans', '10', 'bold'))
        btn2.pack(side='right', padx=5, pady=50, anchor='se')


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        letter = tk.Label(self, text=arr[0], font=("Helvetica", 432))
        letter.pack(side="bottom", expand="YES")


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        letter = tk.Label(self, text="F P", font=("Helvetica", 216))
        letter.pack(side="bottom", expand="YES")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove call to speech at the end, change `command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"),` to `command=controller.on_start,` and add this method near the `show_frame` method:

```
def on_start(self):
    self.show_frame("PageOne")
    speech()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But after i run the code, the speech recognition will start first before the frame change. Do you know why this happened?

Comment: Try with moving `self.update_idletasks()` line bellow `frame.tkraise()` line.

Comment: We won't give up!! xD Try with `self.after_idle(speech)` instead of `speech()`, or with `self.after(speech, 100)` (100 are miliseconds).

Comment: woahh that's works! thank you very much! can i ask you later if i have a question about this?

Comment: :) Just ask, we are here to help.

Comment: sorry, i want to ask again. in this app, i'm going to view letters to eye checker using Snellen chart and the speech recognition will listen user's answer, so i'm confuse to combine the speech recognition's code to the window to view letter. There is many frame to view letter. I'm going to loop the page. can't i do this? because if i make the code to be like this, the first problem is happen again.
    def on_start(self):
        for x in page:
            self.show_frame(x)
            self.after_idle(speechh)

Comment: You should make a passage away from `while True` in your code based on condition and then exit speech, switch frame and call speech again.

Comment: eum sorryy, i forgot to tell that i already remove the while condition in my code. so the problem is not solve yet. I'm sorry for asking too many questionn, but thank youu

Comment: I don't know what ends that `audio = r.listen(source)`, does it return after some defined period of time or what?

Comment: it will listen for a period of time, if there's a speech, then the console will view it, otherwise it will print "Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio"

Comment: Try with removing that `self.update_idletasks()` line and put `self.update()` at the end after `frame.tkraise()`.